# Получить координаты X и Y у функции элемента > style > transform > translate

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно с помощью `js` получить координаты ***X*** и ***Y*** у функции элемента

`> style > transform > translate`

Возможно ли это сделать ?

Если да, то как ?

```html
<img class="chess_com_piece chess_com_draggable" 
src="//images.chesscomfiles.com/chess-themes/pieces/alpha/78/wp.png" 
width="39" 
height="39" 
style="position: absolute; 
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px; 
display: block; 
overflow: hidden; 
opacity: 1; 
width: 39px; 
height: 39px; 
z-index: 11; 
transform: translate(156px, 234px);" />
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так можно получить значение в пикселях, независимо от единиц, в которых задан трансформ.

```js
let img = document.querySelector('img');

// этот вызов вернет матрицу трансформации элемента в виде строки
let matrix = window.getComputedStyle(img).transform;
console.log("matrix =", matrix );

// сделаем из неё массив
matrix = matrix.split(/\(|,\s|\)/).slice(1,7);
console.log("matrix =", JSON.stringify(matrix) );

// сдвиг это 2 последних компонента этой матрицы, нужно понимать что это 
// финальный результат с учетом всех трансформаций, в данном примере это 
// те самые значения что и в свойтве transform, но все иначе если эта матрица 
// получена в результате перемножения матриц нескольких трансформаций
console.log("translate: x =", matrix[4], ",  y =", matrix[5]);

// угол можно найти по формуле, исходя их того, что
// rotate(Xdeg) = matrix(cos(X), sin(X), -sin(X), cos(X), 0, 0);
let angle = Math.asin(matrix[1]) * (180/Math.PI);
console.log("rotate:", angle, 'deg');
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK1my.png?s=48&g=1" 
     style="transform: translate(2em, 22px) rotate(23.45deg)">
```

В более сложных случаях может помочь [unmatrix](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-2d-transforms-20111215/#unmatrix)